# a problem in making hangman game by python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

im Reza
i writen a script for Hangman Game but a there is a problem that for any time in *for_loop* is reseted the text_printed:
this my code::i happing to help me

```
! #usr/bin/Python3
from random import randint
word_list=['reza','ali','mohamad']
r=randint(0,len(word_list)-1)
chosen_word=word_list[r]
inpt=''
char_list=[]
chosen_char=[]
for char in chosen_word:
    char_list.append(char)
while True:
    for i in chosen_word:
        if i == inpt:
            print(i,end='')
        else:
            print('_ ',end='')
    inpt=input("\tPlease enter the word: ")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's happening because you are only printing the current letter `inpt`. You need to store previous chosen letters to know what to print.

Try switching:

```
for i in chosen_word:
    if i == inpt:
        print(i,end='')
    else:
        print('_ ',end='')
```

for

```
print(''.join([letter+' ' if letter in past_letters else '_ ' for letter in chosen_word]))
inpt=input("\tPlease enter the word: ")
past_letters.append(inpt)
```

Here we are basically iterating trough the chosen word, and if the letter beeing iterating has already been chosen, we print it, otherwise we print an underscore